# Unable to Store or Save Session Values in ASPState Database table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session

I'm creating website in Asp.Net (targetFramework="4.0"). I have register with aspnet_regsql.exe using cmd ,which lead to create ASPState Database in Sql Server 2008 R2.

In web.config I have configured with state session mode, code as follow.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True" timeout="20" cookieless="true"></sessionState>
```

My question is that i was unable to store or save the session in ASPState Database table (ASPStateTempApplications and ASPStateTempSessions).

Comment: Please don't add things like `Please help ASAP`, we are an open transparent community, we help when we have time not when you have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my web.config and it is works for me.

```
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=True; Application Name=ProjectName" />
```

Comment: Sorry, here you are.

Comment: Just want to ask Data Source=My Database Name?

Comment: No, it is sql server name, and database is default ASPState, so you don't need to put inside the setting.

Comment: Yup works fine. Thanks Tony.... Just one more question what is datatype for SessionId field. And can we create our own temp table in ASPState database

Comment: SessionID is nvarchar(88), of course, you can create your own temp table, and then manually change the stored procedures to mapping your temp table.